# AWS S3 putObjectFile access denied on some buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been searching the last hour for a solution but can't find any.

I have dozens of buckets on my aws, I was able to read and write to them all fine, they're all mainly in US regions.

But when I created a new bucket in EU(Stockholm) Region, I get the "Access Denied" error when trying to use putObjectFile through PHP. The same script and everything else works fine for all other buckets, except for Eu region buckets. Is there a reason for this?

I can upload files fine through aws console in chrome.

Comment: If you are able to upload fine through AWS Console in your browser, I would suspect maybe a typo when you reference the new bucket in your code. Have you checked about that ?

Comment: Yes, I even copied and pasted the actual name. I did more tests. Created a new bucket in US, and one in EU, US works fine, EU get permission denied. Everything else identical in setup

Comment: Check that you are using the latest version of the PHP SDK for AWS. More recent regions use a different 'signature' style for authenticating requests.

Comment: Thanks John, might be the case. This SDK is a few years old

Comment: Hi Tuan, I'm having a similar issue but with two identical buckets in the same (EU) region. One works, the other doesn't. Did you ever get to the bottom of this?

Comment: @RobertSamarji - I can't remember, but I think it was the SDK that I used was out of date. Use a more current, up to date SDK

Answer (score 1):

You will need to check the following:

- IS the S3 bucket in the same account as the IAM user/role? If not it will need to allow putObject from the user/role that the script uses.
- Attached IAM policies, did the existing IAM policy only cover certain scenarios for buckets i.e. a lockdown on regions. If the policy does not permit the user/role will not be able to connect.
- Check that your S3 bucket to make sure there is no bucket policy applied, if there is then you need to ensure that it allows putObject access.

Comment: Thank you. No policy was applied. I tested creating 2 identical buckets, just different regions and only EU region get access denied ( ASIA Pacific also work fine)

yes, the S3 is in the same account.

Comment: How is your IAM policy attached to the role/user?

Comment: The user as AdministratorAccess policy attached. Is there a setting somewhere that restrict access by regions?

Comment: Are you part of an AWS organisation? Also is it the same user between console and script?

Comment: Not part of an AWS organisation. Console is by main and one login, script is by api key / secret